# inheritance and constuctors | c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

I have a program with a citizen class.
I have another class called "contestant" which inherited from the "citizen" class.
I have a function that adds citizen to an array.
I want to send this function a person and if and to add a check in the function - if this person is a contestant I want add new Contestant to the array, else I want to add a new citizen.

I have a small issue - the parameter I sent to the function is of type citizen
but if I want to add a new contestant I also have to send this contestant party but since I am sending a citizen and I do not sent a party to this function, I can't find a way to add a contestant to the array since my contestant constructor demands the party name.

How can I resolve this issue?
What is the most common solution to this kind of issue?

I've tried casting but it doesn't work..
I am sure there is an elegant solution that doesn't require me to define two separate function or to send the party name as an another parameter.. I just can't find this solution.

so this is the function I wrote and I want to be able to add citizen as contestant to the array of citizens incase the citizen is actually a contestant.

```
    bool ElectionRound::addNewCitizen(const Citizen& citizen)
    //This function add a given citizen into the system.
{
    Citizen newCitizen(citizen);//copy c'tor

    if (1 > citizen.getBallotNum() || citizen.getBallotNum() > bLogSize) //If the ballot Num enterd is not a a ballot which exists return false
    {
        cout << "The ballot num you entered for the citizen doesn't exist.\nThe citizen wasn't added to the voters note.\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (checkIfIdExists(newCitizen.getId(), citizenNote, cLogSize)) //If the id of the new citizen already exists in the system return false
    {
        cout << "\nThe Id num you entered for the citizen alreay exist.\nThe citizen wasn't added to the voters note.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else //Add citizen to the citizen list
    {
        if (cLogSize == cPhySize)//the citizen array is full?
        {
            cPhySize *= 2;
            citizenNote = reallocCitizenArray(citizenNote, cLogSize, cPhySize);//make it bigger.
        }

        citizenNote[cLogSize] = new Citizen(newCitizen);//placement
        cLogSize++;

        int serialNum = newCitizen.getBallotNum();//get the ballot of the citizen.
        for (int i = 0; i < bLogSize; i++)
        {
            if (serialNum == ballotList[i]->getSerialNum())
            {
                ballotList[i]->addVoter(newCitizen);//add the citizen to the correct ballot.
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide [mre] instead of descriptions of code. Code is easier to follow, than descriptions.

Comment: Step 1: Show the code you've written. This helps clarify a *lot* of things right out of the gate. Step 2: Explain what the code does and where you think the problem is.

Comment: Hi, i've edited the question and added the code.

Comment: You seem to be using "person" and "citizen" synonymously. Do you want an array of `Citizen`, or an array of `Citizen*`?

Comment: Generally you can't have a container of a base class type and assign subclasses to it as they'd have to be copied into the base class and thus lose information. So you typically have a container of **pointers** to the base class and you can happily add pointers to the subclasses to the container. Since this is C++ I definitely recommend STL containers and smart pointers instead like `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Person>>`

Comment: Hi @Beta, you are right, I ment to write citizen, I've edited my post. Thanks